# Javascript date not a number

Tags: javascript, date, error-handling, nan

I need to compute a sum of two input: a date and a number of days. The values of number of days are: [0, 30, 30 end of month,60, 60 end of month, 90, 90 end of month, 120, 120 end of month]. 
I performed this task as follow:

```
{name:'terms',index:'terms', editable:true,edittype: "select", editoptions: {
        dataEvents: [
        {
            type: 'change',
            fn: function(e) {
                var current_date = $(e.target).val();
                var form = $(e.target).closest('form.FormGrid');
                var dateCommit = $('#Data_consegna_richiesta',form[0]).val();
                var termsDue = $('#terms',form[0]).val();
                aData2 = dateCommit.split("/");
                data2 = "" + aData2[1] + "/" + aData2[0] + "/" + aData2[2];

                if(termsDue.split(" ").length != 1 ){
                    d = new Date(data2);
                    d.setDate(d.getDate() + parseInt(termsDue.toString().split(" ")[0])) ;
                    var curr_date = d.getDate();
                    var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 2;
                    var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
                    var outDate = new Date(curr_year,curr_month,0);
                    $('#date_commitment',form[0]).val(outDate.getDate() + "/"+ outDate.getMonth()+"/"+outDate.getFullYear());
                }
                else{
                    d1 = new Date(data2);
                    d1.setDate(d1.getDate() + parseInt(termsDue));
                    var curr_date = d1.getDate();
                    var curr_month = d1.getMonth() + 1;
                    var curr_year = d1.getFullYear();
                    $('#date_commitment',form[0]).val(curr_date+"/"+curr_month+"/"+curr_year);
                }


            }
        }
    ],
value: "0:0;30:30;30 end of month: 30 end of month;60:60;60 end of month: 60 end of month;90:90; 90 end of month:90 end of month; 120:120; 120 end of month: 120 end of month"},
width:70, search: true },
```

It works, but when I set the value to 90, 90 end of month, 120 and 120 end of month the result is: NaN\NaN\NaN.
Anyone knows why adding up to 90 days I receive this error?
The format of the date is: dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: `data2 = "" + aData2[1] + "/" + aData2[0] + "/" + aData2[2]` should be `new Date(aData2[2], aData2[1]-1, aData2[0])`. Won't fix your issue, but will avoid any parsing issues. Months are zero indexed (Jan=0, Feb=1, etc.), I don't see you allowing for that anywhere.

Comment: yes I know but I use it just to "plot" out the date in my format